# What is an Abstract Data Type (ADT)?

Tags: data-structures

I came across the following definition of an 'Abstract Data Type' which I am unable to comprehend. Could someone explain, preferably with an example?

> An abstract data type is defined as a mathematical model of the data objects that make up a data type as well as the functions that operate on these objects

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

Answer (score 5):

In some language, it doesn't matter what, I could give you the following:

```
Stack make_stack();
void push(Stack stack, value);
value pop(Stack stack);
```

Then I could say, suppose you want to push three values onto the stack and then pop one off. It might look like this:

```
Stack my_stack = make_stack();
push(my_stack, 14);             /* stack now contains: 14 */
push(my_stack, "foo");          /* stack now contains: 14 foo */
push(my_stack, 999);            /* stack now contains: 14 foo 999 */
x = pop(my_stack);              /* x = 999, stack contains 14 foo */
```

This is an abstract data type: I have defined a new type, a stack, and I have given you an abstract interface to it. That is, I have given you the data object that makes up the data type, as you put it, in the form of `Stack` and I have given you the functions `make_stack`, `push` and `pop` to operate on it.

The stack could be implemented by lists, or an array, or a heap or something else entirely, and there's no externally visible way to know what. All you do know is that there is a particular API you use with it, and that API guarantees you get stack-like behavior. This stack is an abstract data type.

Comment: Thank you Lyons, for your valuable reply . one more Doubt will abstract data type is a kind of user defined data type derived from basic data type (int,float,char)???

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. An abstract data type can be provided by the language or the user. It can't be a bare native type because that exposes the implementation, but it can wrap one.